# how to disable minutes for a specific hour in datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

need some help with this, using datetimepicker.js with moment.js I am playing with a booking calendar where I just can pick an hour from 11:00 am to 7:30 pm.

Right now I am being able to set the limit untill 8:00pm (since I don't know how to do it with minutes in a spefic hour, in this case 7pm)

this is the code I have so far:

```
var date= new Date();
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment().add(1, 'd'),
    minDate: (date.getTime() + 1 * 86400000),
    disabledHours: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23],
    disabledDates: [
                        moment("08/4/2018"), //holiday                    
    ],
    locale: "es", //language
    format: 'Y/m/d A HH:mm',
    inline: true,
    sideBySide: true  
});
```

And this is what I don't want to happen

[image]

limit hour has to be 7:30pm, can't be booked over that

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`disabledTimeIntervals`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#disabledtimeintervals):

```
disabledTimeIntervals: [
    [moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 11 })],
    [moment({ h: 19, m: 30 }), moment({ h: 24 })]
],
```

This option added for version >= [`4.13.28`](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/commit/ff6a2c2e15953193534f516962a944ce6672a333)